Recursive nested ul ordered by depth
I am creating a nested list from an array generated from an hierarchical table of categories, with subcategories having a parent  ID of the parent category ID. I am trying to display the list in a format like folders and files, where list items with more items in them are grouped together like folders followed by those that don't, let's call them files.
I have managed to create the list but each set of categories and subcategories are displaying in alphabetical order as opposed to the desired format outlined below. I have tried to achieve the desired format inside the recursive function as well as a separate function targeting these "folders" after the list has been generated.
The desired outcome would look like this:
<ul id='myList' class="folder">
  <li data-id=0>
    <ul class="folder">
      <li data-id=1>catA
        <ul class="folder">
          <li data-id=3>catA_1
          <ul>
            <li data-id=4>catA_1_1</li>
          </ul> 
          <ul>
            <li data-id=5>catA_1_2</li>
          </ul> 
          <ul>
            <li data-id=6>catA_1_3</li>
          </ul>                              
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="folder">
          <li data-id=8>catA_3
            <ul>
              <li data-id=9>catA_3_1</li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li data-id=10>catA_3_2</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="folder">
              <li data-id=11>catA_3_3
                <ul>
                  <li data-id=12>catA_3_3_1</li>
                </ul>
                <ul data-id=13>catA_3_3_2</ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li data-id=7>catA_2</li>  <!-- *Note these two (data-id = 7 & 14) trail the above "folders" as they have no items in them -->
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li data-id=14>catA_4</li>
        </ul>               
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li data-id=2>catB</li> <!-- And so on with catB -->
    </ul>    
  </li>
</ul>



  const src = [[1,"catA",0],[2,"catB",0],[3,"catA_1",1],[4,"catA_1_1",3],[5,"catA_1_2",3],[6,"catA_1_3",3],[7,"catA_2",1],[8,"catA_3",1],[9,"catA_3_1",8],[10,"catA_3_2",8],[11,"catA_3_3",8],[12,"catA_3_3_1",11],[13,"catA_3_3_2",11],[14,"catA_4",1],[15,"catB_1",2],[16,"catB_1_1",15],[17,"catB_1_2",16],[18,"catB_1_3",16],[19,"catB_2",15],[20,"catB_3",15],[21,"catB_3_1",20],[22,"catB_3_2",20],[23,"catB_3_3",20],[24,"catB_3_3_1",23],[25,"catB_3_3_2",23],[26,"catB_4",15]];

function tree(src, parent = 0) {
  const el = document.getElementById("myList").querySelector("li[data-id='" + parent + "']");
  
  if (!el) return;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
    if (src[i][2] === parent) {
      const new_parent = src[i][0];
      el.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<ul><li data-id='" + new_parent + "'>" + src[i][1] + "</li></ul>");
      el.parentElement.classList.add("folder");
      tree(src, new_parent);
    }
  }
}

tree(src)
<ul id='myList'>
  <li data-id=0></li>
</ul>



EDIT: To clarify, the commmented li with data-id=7, (catA_2) is currently being placed alphabetically between two ".folder" ul's instead of after the ".folder" ul's

Does your code produce the desired outcome? What is px (referring to the part of the code that calls px.tree(....)?

Oops! That px came from my actual code. Edited it out now. No, that function is ordering alphabetically, meaning that catA_2 would be slotted in as a "file" between "folders"

No, that function is ordering alphabetically - doesn't seem to be alphabetical order, seems reverse alphabetical order

I think you're right. Getting a little lost in providing example code vs actual code. My actual code is ordered in reverse alphabet so that this would result in correct alphabet

did you want "beforeend" instead of "afterend" maybe?

possibly but I feel that may be irrelevant to sorting by parent ids and depth

irrelevant except that it results in the desired outcome

No actually it does not. There are still files mixed in between folders, just in different alphabet order

can you make your example even more minimal to reproduce the issue?

Not sure about that. It's fairly minimal as is. I know the desired list is pretty long but I've commented out the important parts. Would be hard to demonstrate with any less

Are you sure that you want every list item to belong to a list of one item? None of your nested lists have more than one item in them. Semantically, that doesn't seem correct.

No I am not sure! It does seem a bit wrong

Also, are you sure that a parent item will come first in the array, before any of its children? Or does the function need to be robust enough to still work if the order is jumbled

No the array is sorted alphabetically by category name so parents and children are all over the place

yes as in any li which contains ul should all come before those that don't thus resembling a window of folders and files where folders come first alphabetically followed by files alphabetically

Can you give a definite answer to @Sean comment - it seems really weird to have individual items in their own individual lists.

I'm trying to rework it so that it's not the case that each item is its own ul but having a hard time figuring it out how not to. This loop is making me loopy. I guess it should be that just each ".folder" is a ul

Thanks for the clarification. Not sure I’d bother with any fancy recursion but would just plod through with a for loop.

I think you're looking for something like this.
It first converts the array of arrays to an object of objects. Then it adds each child to its parent item. Then it sorts them so that items with children come before items without children. Then it recursively generates the markup.
(Note: I'm using different sample data because the data in the original question has some inconsistencies between parent IDs and names).
If the data is alphabetized, it's semantically more correct to use an ordered list instead of an unordered list because there's an inherent order to the data.


const src = [[1, "catA", 0], [2, "catA_1", 1], [3, "catA_1_1", 2], [4, "catA_1_2", 2], [5, "catA_2", 1], [7, "catB", 0], [8, "catB_1", 7], [9, "catB_1_1", 8], [10, "catB_2", 7], [11, "catB_2_1", 10], [12, "catA_3", 1], [13, "catA_3_1", 12], [14, "catA_3_2", 12], [15, "catA_3_1_1", 13], [16, "catA_3_1_2", 13], [17, "catA_3_2_1", 14], [18, "catA_3_2_2", 14]]

function buildNestedList(src) {
  
  const nodes = {}
  const rootNodes = []

  // build an object of the items, with each item's id as the key
  src.forEach(([id, name, parentId]) => {
    nodes[id] = { id, name, parentId, children: [] }
  })

  // build the tree structure
  Object.values(nodes).forEach((node) => {
    if (node.parentId === 0) {
      rootNodes.push(node)
    } else {
      const parent = nodes[node.parentId]
      if (parent) {
        parent.children.push(node)
      } else {
        console.warn(`Parent with ID ${node.parentId} not found for node ID ${node.id}`)
      }
    }
  })

  // sort nodes: first alphabetically by name, then prioritize those with children
  function sortNodes(nodes) {
    // sort alphabetically first
    nodes.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
    // then sort by whether they have children (those with children first)
    return nodes.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.children.length > 0 && b.children.length === 0) {
        return -1
      } else if (a.children.length === 0 && b.children.length > 0) {
        return 1
      }
      return 0
    })
  }

  // recursive function to create dom elements
  function createList(nodes) {
    const ol = document.createElement("ol")
    sortNodes(nodes).forEach((node) => {
      const li = document.createElement("li")
      li.textContent = node.name
      li.dataset.id = node.id
      if (node.children.length > 0) {
        li.appendChild(createList(node.children))
      }
      ol.appendChild(li)
    })
    return ol
  }

  // generate and return the hierarchy
  return createList(rootNodes)
  
}

document.body.appendChild(buildNestedList(src))




My bad on the source data inconsistencies! Thanks for this great explanation, it seems like a much neater way of going about things. It is almost perfect but for items number 2 & 3 of catA ol should be reversed as catA_2, having no children, should come after catA_3

@midget I've modified it so that items with children come before items without children.

You are the main dude! It's so close and I should be able to take it from here but it seems each ol is then ordered by data-id  instead of textContent alphapetically

Actually it turns out I don't know how to rearrange the li's alphabetically

I've updated it to sort alphabetically (while still keeping the items with children first). If this solves your problem, be sure to upvote and accept the answer

lol I swear I made that exact same adjustment but to no avail. Copy and pasted your code and it works like a charm. Sean is a champion! Thank you immensely for all your help on this

Actually I put curly braces around "a.name.localeCompare(b.name)" which prevented the alphabetical sorting

Yeah, if you add braces you also have to add an explicit return
